# Jenkins Execute Groovy Script Before Loading Plugins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, plugins, lifecycle

I need to change some plugin config files before plugins are loaded. I looked into the `init.groovy.d`, however it seems to run Groovy scripts in that directory after plugins have been loaded and therefore would require a restart to apply. Is there a way to run Groovy scripts before Jenkins loads the plugins?

Comment: @IanW Hello Ian, I essentially want to load credentials for the Mailer plugin during runtime. Is it possible to write a script to re-configure the plugin in init.groovy.d? Or possibly reload the configuration file without restarting?

Comment: You're right, I believe you've answered both of my questions. I appreciate the responses @IanW !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are requesting is not necessary. Generally, when adding plugins, they come unconfigured. Jenkins starts, loads the plugins, then you can configure via [`init.groovy`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Jenkins+upon+start+up), [`CasC`](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/), etc., similar to you adding via GUI (add, restart, configure).

We start w/war file, wrapper, init.groovy.d, plus a variant of the docker [`install_plugins.sh`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh). Other than the war, the wrapper and wrapper.conf, install_plugins.sh and plugin list, and all the init scripts are controlled in a git repo, which we pull down.
dumping the plugins into the plugins dir, then launch [`jenkins.sh`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/jenkins.sh).

The `init.groovy` [runs automatically](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script) after initialization and configures all system, global, tools and plugins values, as well as credentials values, also creating/configuring nodes.

*NB: best to use 1 init script per section or plugin as a failure in any init script will quietly fail, effectively skipping the rest of the script.*

You may need to `.save()` after setting most parameters via init.goovy. Perhaps that's why you did not see the changes.

If you were really paranoid, you could first invoke `Hudson.instance.`[`doQuietDown()`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#doQuietDown-boolean-int-), which effective blocks the queue (multiple init.groovy scripts execute in [lexical order](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Hook+Script)), do all the configurations, then invoke [`doCancelQuietDown()`](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#doCancelQuietDown--), but we'd had no issues w/o that.

This approach (init.groovy.d) works fine, but looking to switch to JCasC now that it's matured. CasC is a simpler to manage (again, using separate config files for each plugin) and read.